# if statements 'leaking' intro each other Batch

Tags: batch, batch-file

OK, so I'm creating a math game in batch for school(because I thought it would be easier) I came across an odd problem when using if statements. So, basically when I enter 2 into the command line it goes to a line in the MIDDLE of an if statement inside another if statement it wasn't even supposed to go into.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:Start
@echo start game(1) or join game(2) note:game must be started for P2 to join
set /p YN=

IF %YN%==1 (
@echo creating files...
if not exist quizFiles (
    md "quizFiles"
)
@echo P1> quizFiles/gameState.txt
@echo 48> quizFiles/cards.txt
@echo.0> quizFiles/P1Score.txt
@echo.0> quizFiles/P2Score.txt
@echo false> quizFiles/P2Joined.txt
set /a gameMode=%RANDOM% %%4
@echo.!gameMode!> quizFiles/gameMode.txt
IF "!gameMode!"=="0" (
    set gameMode=LCM
) ELSE IF "!gameMode!"=="1" (
set gameMode=GCF
) ELSE IF "!gameMode!"=="2" (
    set gameMode=Muliplication of fractions
) ELSE IF "!gameMode!"=="3" (
    set gameMode=Division of fractions
)
@echo.!gameMode!
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
@echo waiting for other player to join...
set dot="2"
:WP2
set /p P2Joined=<quizFiles/P2Joined.txt
IF NOT "!P2Joined!"=="true" (
    timeout /t 2 /nobreak > NUL
    @echo waiting...
    GOTO WP2
)
@echo joined
:P1G
    set /p cardsRemaining=<quizFiles/cards.txt
    @echo cards left: !cardsRemaining!
    set /p P1Score=<quizFiles/P1Score.txt
    @echo P1 has: !P1Score! cards
    set /p P2Score=<quizFiles/P2Score.txt
    @echo P2 has: !P2Score! cards
    set /p currentPlayer=<quizFiles/gameState.txt
    @echo It is now !currentPlayer!'s turn
    @echo 4 cards chosen
    set /p gameMode=<quizFiles/gameMode.txt
    IF "!gameMode!"=="0" (
        set /a card1=%RANDOM% %%96
        set /a card2=%RANDOM% %%96
        set /a card3=%RANDOM% %%96
        set /a card4=%RANDOM% %%96
    )
    @echo card1: !card1!
    @echo card2: !card2!
    @echo card3: !card3!
    @echo card4: !card4!
    IF "!gameMode!"=="0" (
        @echo choose your first card(1-4)
        set /p chosenCard1=
        @echo choose your second card(1-4)
        set /p chosenCard2= <<<< leaks here
        @echo what is the LCM of these two cards
        set /p userAnswer=
    )
GOTO P1G
) ELSE IF %YN%==2 (
    @echo joining game...
    @echo true> quizFiles/P2Joined.txt
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
    @echo joined
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: `set /a gameMode=%RANDOM% %%4` doesn't seem to be correct ...

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Comment: how does that relate to the question asked?

Comment: How does what relate?

Comment: your first comment and it does work btw

Comment: No it doesn't. `set /a gameMode=1550 %4` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: but that's not what I wrote

Comment: It what is executed when you run the batch file.

Comment: Remove the `echo off` and run the batch file.

Comment: @DavidPostill - ??? You have lost me as well. `set /a gameMode=%RANDOM% %%4` simply sets gameMode to a number from 0 to 3, which makes perfect sense with the OP's code.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Well almost makes sense - delayed expansion is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your script, for instance (maybe incomplete):

(1) What-if a user just hits only <kbd>ENTER</kbd> in response to `set /p YN=`? Use double quotes as follows `IF "%YN%"=="1" (` or consider switching to [`CHOICE` command](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) which allows single key-presses to be captured from the keyboard.

(2) Why do you use the same variable `gameMode` to store so different things?

(3 - **important**) Closing parenthesis in `echo choose your second card(1-4)` used in a parenthesized code block would close it. Either [escape it as `echo … card(1-4^)`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) or use parentheses of another form e.g. square brackets as in `echo … card [1-4]`.

(4 - **most important**) [**Never** use `:label` nor `:: label-like comment` inside a command block enclosed in `()` parentheses.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32147995/3439404) Create and [Call a subroutine](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) instead. You can `goto` ad libitum inside such procedure body.

(5) `%RANDOM%` inside a command block enclosed in `()` parentheses evaluates to the same number. Hence, all `card1`, `card2`, `card3` and `card4` in following code snippet are the same:

```
IF "!gameMode!"=="0" (
    set /a card1=%RANDOM% %%96
    set /a card2=%RANDOM% %%96
    set /a card3=%RANDOM% %%96
    set /a card4=%RANDOM% %%96
)
```

Moreover, not even using `!RANDOM!` instead of `%RANDOM%` could guarantee different values. Compare `:dragNthCard` procedure below.

[Useful Dbenham's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1142737/if-statements-leaking-intro-each-other-batch/1142856?noredirect=1#comment1641769_1142856) inspired me to play a bit with your code. Here's a raw draft (working in some sense which could not match your aim perfectly). Implemented `LCM` and `GCF` as one-round quiz for both initiator *P1* and joined *P2*: the same task, different card sets.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:Start
@echo note:game must be started for P2 to join
CHOICE /C 12Q /M "start game (1) or join game (2) or quit game (Q)"
set "YN=%errorlevel%"
IF errorlevel 3 goto :eof
IF errorlevel 2 (
    @echo joining game...
    @echo true> quizFiles/P2Joined.txt
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
    @echo joined
) ELSE (
    @echo creating files...
    if not exist quizFiles md "quizFiles"
    @echo P1> quizFiles/gameState.txt
    @echo 48> quizFiles/cards.txt
    @echo.0> quizFiles/P1Score.txt
    @echo.0> quizFiles/P2Score.txt
    @echo false> quizFiles/P2Joined.txt
    set /a gameMode=%RANDOM% %%4
    echo gameMode !gameMode!
    @echo.!gameMode!> quizFiles/gameMode.txt
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
    @echo waiting for other player to join...
    call :waitToJoin
)
rem commont part for both initiator P1 and joined P2

call :dragCards
REM currently implemented only one round game 
REM 
REM set /p cardsRemaining=<quizFiles/cards.txt
REM @echo cards left: !cardsRemaining!
REM set /p P1Score=<quizFiles/P1Score.txt
REM @echo P1 has: !P1Score! cards
REM set /p P2Score=<quizFiles/P2Score.txt
REM @echo P2 has: !P2Score! cards
REM set /p currentPlayer=<quizFiles/gameState.txt
REM @echo It is now !currentPlayer!'s turn
REM 
@echo 4 cards chosen
set /p gameMode=<quizFiles/gameMode.txt
IF "!gameMode!"=="0" (
    set gameModeText=LCM
) ELSE IF "!gameMode!"=="1" (
set gameModeText=GCF
) ELSE IF "!gameMode!"=="2" (
    set gameModeText=Multiplication of fractions
) ELSE IF "!gameMode!"=="3" (
    set gameModeText=Division of fractions
)
echo gameMode !gameMode! !gameModeText!
set "rightAnswer=nonsens"
IF "!gameMode!"=="0" (
    call :Choose2Cards
    call :%gameModeText% !chosenCard1! !chosenCard2!
)
IF "!gameMode!"=="1" (
    call :Choose2Cards
    call :%gameModeText% !chosenCard1! !chosenCard2!
)
IF "!gameMode!"=="3" call :Choose2Cards & rem not implemented yet
IF "!gameMode!"=="4" call :Choose2Cards & rem not implemented yet
IF "%rightAnswer%"=="nonsens" (
    echo not implemented yet: %gameModeText%
) else (
    If "%userAnswer%"=="%rightAnswer%" (
      echo %userAnswer% is right 
    ) ELSE (
      echo %userAnswer% is wrong; right answer = %rightAnswer%
    )
)

rem PAUSE

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::
:::  Your script continues here: save score, loop next round etc.
:::
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:LCM
rem Least common multiple usage: call :lcm <input1> <input2>
rem by https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Batch_File
set "_aux1=%1"
set "_aux2=%2"
:lcmSub
if %2 equ 0 (
    set /a rightAnswer = %_aux1%*%_aux2%/%1
    rem echo rightAnswer = !rightAnswer!
    goto :EOF
)
set /a res = %1 %% %2
call :lcmSub %2 %res%
goto :eof

:GCF
rem Greatest common factor / divisor
rem by https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Batch_File
if %2 equ 0 (
    set rightAnswer=%1
    rem echo rightAnswer = !rightAnswer!
    goto :eof
)
set /a res = %1 %% %2
call :gcf %2 %res%
goto :eof

:Muliplication
goto :eof
:Division
goto :eof

:waitToJoin
  set dot="2"
  :WP2
  set /p P2Joined=<quizFiles/P2Joined.txt
  IF NOT "!P2Joined!"=="true" (
      timeout /t 2 /nobreak > NUL
      @echo waiting...
      GOTO WP2
  )
  @echo joined
goto :eof

:dragCards
:P1G
  for /L %%N in (1,1,4) do (
      call :dragNthCard %%N 
      echo card%%N: !card%%~N!
  )
goto :eof 

:Choose2Cards
    CHOICE /C 1234 /M "choose your first  card "
    set "chosenCard1=!card%errorlevel%!"
    :Choose2CardsDifferent
    CHOICE /C 1234 /M "choose your second card "
    set "chosenCard2=!card%errorlevel%!"
    If %chosenCard1% EQU %chosenCard2% goto :Choose2CardsDifferent
    echo what is the %gameModeText% of these two cards: %chosenCard1% and %chosenCard2%
    set /p "userAnswer=%gameModeText%( %chosenCard1%, %chosenCard2%) = "
goto :eof 

:dragNthCard
  set "_cardNo=%~1"
  set /A _cardMax=%_cardNo% - 1
  :dragNthAgain
  set /a card%_cardNo%=%RANDOM% %%96
  for /L %%G in (1,1,%_cardMax%) do (
    if !card%_cardNo%! EQU !card%%G! (
      timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
      goto :dragNthAgain
    )
  )
  rem echo CARD%_cardNo%: !card%_cardNo%!
goto :eof
```

Comment: All points are good. But 4) would be better with a suggestion on what to do instead. Point 5) is correct, but cryptic. It is not obvious that your are pointing out two flaws in that one item - Delayed expansion should be used, and the logic needs to change to make sure the player never "draws" the same card twice.

Comment: @dbenham answer updated. Please excuse my feeling that I'm more fluent in `.bat` language than in English:) Therefore I gave such a baroque code snippet…